# How should I define the camera frames in my robot's URDF?

Tags: urdf, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a URDF model for my robot and two cameras mounted on the robot's head (a Bumblebee and an Asus Xtion). My question is, how do I define the camera link frames and the frames for each of the cameras? Do I estimate the location of each, e.g. in solidworks?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105866/how-should-i-define-the-camera-frames-in-my-robot%27s-urdf?/) by [sofiad](https://answers.ros.org/users/8786/sofiad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2013-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you have to estimate the location and orientation of your camera with respect to the parent link that the camera is attached to.

In [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/UnderstandingPR2URDF#CA-27a380b7379ee7d82de732cd1a9a3490da1152cd_110), you can see a robot example and how the cameras are defined and also how the "origin" of each camera is implemented in this [XACRO](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_common/blob/indigo-devel/pr2_description/urdf/sensors/wge100_camera.urdf.xacro) file.

---

Originally posted by [romay](https://answers.ros.org/users/20402/romay/) with karma: 56 on 2015-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1